# Residual Networks - Non-image use cases

Tags: neural-networks, residual-networks

I've been doing some research into computer vision lately and constantly come across the ability of residual networks to improve performance. Intuitively I think I grasp them, however, I struggle to understand why they are not more prolific in other non-image based fields. I'm currently specialized in NLP and I rarely see them.

My question is, what non-image use-cases have you seen residual networks succeed? And why do you think they did?

Answer (score 1):

Residual Networks are designed to avoid the vanishing gradient problem in deep neural networks. LSTM cells, which are commonly used in NLP, have a 'natural' way to avoid these, see e.g. ([How does LSTM prevent the vanishing gradient problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185639/264183)).

However there is research using residual connections combined with LSTMs for NLP, see [Google's Neural Machine Translation System: Bridging the Gap between Human and Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08144).