# Is GRU the minimum/simplest RNN to prevent vanishing or exploding?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I learned from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263956/103153) and [this post](https://weberna.github.io/blog/2017/11/15/LSTM-Vanishing-Gradients.html) that the forget gate in LSTM controls which information to vanish and which not, but I wonder if the LSTM or GRU is the minimum/simplest RNN to accomplish that(resistance to exploding and vanishing gradients)? If not which RNN structure is?

By simplicity, I mean fewer connections and fewer matrices, and the performance is irrelevant here. For instance, GRU has fewer connections and matrices than LSTM, so it is simpler. I mention LSTM and GRU because they are the most popular RNNs for that sake.

Comment: A single GRU is "simpler" in the sense that it does not have as many trainable weights and biases as a single LSTM unit. On the other hand, it's commonly found that one needs more GRU units to have comparable performance to a neural network using LSTM units on the same task with the same data. In what sense are you measuring "simplicity"?

Comment: This paper compares a number of different recurrent network and finds no clear winner among them, when the networks are compared across diverse tasks. Jozefowicz et al., ["An Empirical Exploration of Recurrent Network Architecture"](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/jozefowicz15.pdf)

Comment: And another LSTM architecture search paper. Greff et al., ["LSTM: A Search Space Odyssey"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04069.pdf) where none of the variants significantly improve over the vanilla LSTM. The LSTM with coupled input/forget gates might be noteworthy, because the coupling reduces the parameter count.

Comment: @Sycorax I mean fewer connections and fewer matrices, and the performance is irrelevant here.